# Mysterious 50-100 ms delay every few requests to same HTTP endpoint

Tags: http, .net-4.5, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to improve the performance of a desktop application that makes 1000's of HTTP POST requests to a REST service. According to Fiddler, the server consistently responds to each request in 40-50 ms. However, whether I use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to make the request, and whether I use a synchronous or asynchronous method to do so, **every 3rd or 4th call mysteriously takes an extra 50-100 ms to return**. The remaining method calls only take an extra 1-2 ms relative to the network timing.

Typical timings (in milliseconds) for 10 consecutive requests look like this:

```
Network    Method call    Difference
========   ============   ===========
54         167            113 - ??
43         141            97 - ??
42         43             1
42         43             1
40         106            62 - ??
44         44             0
41         41             0
44         115            71 - ??
41         41             0
38         39             1
```

You can see the delay gaps in this Fiddler timeline:

[image: Fiddler timeline with gaps]

Here's the synchronous WebClient version:

```cs
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.BaseAddress = m_endpoint.AbsoluteUri;

// ...add authentication and content headers...

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var responseStr = wc.UploadString(pathAndQuery, "POST", bodyStr);
sw.Stop();

Debug.Print("HTTP request: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Here's the async WebClient version:

```cs
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var responseStr = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(pathAndQuery, "POST", bodyStr);
sw.Stop();
```

The HttpClient version is almost identical:

```cs
m_client = new HttpClient();
m_client.BaseAddress = m_endpoint;

// ...add authentication and content headers...

var content = new StringContent(bodyStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var response = await m_client.PostAsync(pathAndQuery, content, cancelToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
sw.Stop();

Debug.Print("HTTP request: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

All of these implementations exhibit this issue. My local computer is otherwise idle, and requests are being sent one at a time (no concurrency).

Can anyone point me to what might be causing these mysterious delays?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Garbage collector? Check the performance counter for "% time in garbage collector" and see if the spikes align with your delays.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem to this.  Research "Nagle's Algorithm" and "Delayed Acknowledgements".

Comment: @vtortola Thanks for the suggestion. I added calls to [GC.CollectionCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collectioncount(v=vs.110).aspx) for generations 0 and 1, before and after the series of requests. No collections were reported during that interval, so I don't think GC is the issue.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I think that may have been the issue. When I started using the REST service's batching feature (which means fewer, larger requests), the problem seemed to go away. Batching also meant any residual effect was less of a factor in the overall throughput.